# Como pegar a posição do mouse (x e y) no console? C++

Tags: c++, console

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    int x = 150;
    int y = 150;

    COLORREF COLOR = RGB(255, 255, 255);

    SetPixel(mydc, x, y, COLOR);

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Onde é desenhado um pixel na coordenada (150, 150) do console.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar a coordenada da posição do mouse, para utiliza-lo para desenhar tal pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumo que seu código é específico para windows (`windows.h`).

Em ambientes Windows você pode utilizar a função [`GetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390(VS.85).aspx) para obter a posição do cursor em relação à tela.

Para traduzir as coordenadas de maneira a obter posições relativas à janela você pode usar a função [`ScreenToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952(VS.85).aspx).

```
POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);
ScreenToClient(HWND, &pt);
// pt.x e pt.y guardam as coordenadas
```

---

**Referência**: [SOen- Get current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423739/664577)

Comment: Funcinou, vlw :D